# High quality educational reading and math games (K-4)

Tags: educational

I grew up on Schoolhouse Rock, Jumpstart, and Math Blaster.

I'm looking for comparable applications, but without the Windows 98 requirement.

Requirements:

- Educational for reading or math subjects, somewhere in the 4-10 age range.
- No ads or in-app purchases
- Very easy for kids to use
- Reasonable quantity of content
- Overall high-quality
- Runs on at least one Windows, macOS, or browser version

Answer (score 1):

Scratch (https://scratch.mit.edu/) is a free and open-source platform to help children learn to programme. People have developed many exciting and fun projects which will fulfil your needs. 
Also, children will love to learn the insights of programming, mathematics while learning to code. We were running a Dojo a year ago where we used to teach the same. You should definitely check out the "scratch."

Free and open source.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[GCompris](https://gcompris.net/) is a suite of educational activities for kids aged 2-10.

Free and open source, it runs on Linux, macOS and Windows.

List of activities, from their official website:

> computer discovery: keyboard, mouse, touchscreen ...
>   reading: letters, words, reading practice, typing text ...
>   arithmetic: numbers, operations, table memory, enumeration, double entry table ...
>   science: the canal lock, the water cycle, renewable energy ...
>   geography: countries, regions, culture ...
>   games: chess, memory, align 4, hangman, tic-tac-toe ...
>   other: colors, shapes, Braille, learn to tell time ...

Screenshot:

[image]

It has been maintained since 20 years ago.